# Salting a password with a "joined" datetime

Tags: php, security, salt

I've seen this information in other articles but most were salting with a known value (like a username). Is salting a password with the `joined` datetime (or an MD5 of the `joined` datetime) a secure way of further securing credentials if the `joined` data is not exposed anywhere in the site?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Salt with a truly random salt instead. Guessing a date based salt seems a little too easy, especially if someone is aware how long the person has been a member of the site.

You could do something like:

```
$salt = substr(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, 16);
```

Comment: +1: Salt should **always** be random and different for each user.

Comment: @TaylorOtwell Fair enough! I was thinking that since it had the time down to the second and I could MD5 it as well I could avoid adding another field into the user database. Thanks.

Comment: @cbh - Yeah, you'll need to go ahead and add a "salt" field. It will be much more secure.

Comment: @TaylorOtwell Done. And I suppose I should update the salt if the user changes the password? Or is that unnecessary?

Comment: @cbh - Go for it. Couldn't hurt.

Comment: All that matters is that you can reapply the same salt each time you create that hash. And make it as unique as possible - a cryptographically strong random salt for each hash instance is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did something like this:

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
$salt_shaker = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
$salted = $password.$salt_shaker;
```